# PowerShell multiline match with regex

Tags: regex, powershell

Folks.

I'm trying to get a signature from the script.
But each multiline match in PowerShell, which I'm doing not catching it.

The idea to catch lines of ===== and everything between them.

```
$Content = @'
Function Show-Example
{
    #Some text
    Another text
    Even more text with : like that.

    ==============================
    Org: Home Garage Inc.
    Author: Mr.Smit
    Created: 12/12/2021
    Last update: 12/12/2021
    Version: 1.1.1
    ==============================

    Other text
    And More text { Some blocks of code }
    Even more not interesting text :-)

}
'@

$FilePath = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop"

Set-Content -Value $Content -Path "$FilePath\Example_File.ps1"

$Content = Get-Content -Path "$FilePath\Example_File.ps1"

$Signature = $Content | Select-String -Pattern '(?smi)(====.+====(\n.+){1,}){1,}'

$Signature
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `Get-Content -Path "$FilePath\Example_File.ps1" -Raw`. And then the regex should be `(?ms)^\s*===+\s*(.*?)\r?\n\s*====`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Content = @'
Function Show-Example
{
    #Some text
    Another text
    Even more text with : like that.

    ==============================
    Org: Home Garage Inc.
    Author: Mr.Smit
    Created: 12/12/2021
    Last update: 12/12/2021
    Version: 1.1.1
    ==============================

    Other text
    And More text { Some blocks of code }
    Even more not interesting text :-)

}
'@ -split '\r?\n'

$between = $false
switch -regex ($Content) {
    '[=]{3,}' {
        $between = !$between
    }
    Default {
        if ($between) {
            $_
        }
    }
}
```

OR if you want to use a file directly as the input to `switch`

```
$file = 'C:\temp\powershell\test_lines.ps1'
$between = $false
switch -regex -File $file {
    '[=]{3,}' {
        $between = !$between
    }
    Default {
        if ($between) {
            $_
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to pass the `-Raw` option when you `Get-Content` from a file to read it into a single string variable (else, it will be processed line by line, not as a  single string).

Then, you need to use

```cs
(?sm)^\s*===+\s*(.*?)\r?\n\s*====
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fsm%29%5E%5Cs*%3D%3D%3D%2B%5Cs*%28.*%3F%29%5Cr%3F%5Cn%5Cs*%3D%3D%3D%3D&i=Function%20Show-Example%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%23Some%20text%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Another%20text%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Even%20more%20text%20with%20%3A%20like%20that.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Org%3A%20Home%20Garage%20Inc.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Author%3A%20Mr.Smit%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Created%3A%2012%2F12%2F2021%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Last%20update%3A%2012%2F12%2F2021%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Version%3A%201.1.1%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Other%20text%0D%0A%20%20%20%20And%20More%20text%20%7B%20Some%20blocks%20of%20code%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Even%20more%20not%20interesting%20text%20%3A-%29%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D). The value between `===`s will be in Group 1.

*Details*

- `(?sm)` - multiline and singleline modes on
- `^` - start of a line
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `===+` - three or more `=` chars
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `\r?\n` - CRLF or LF line break
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `====` - four `=` chars.

You may get it into Group 0, too:

```cs
(?sm)(?<=^\s*===+\r?\n\s*).*?(?=\r?\n\s*====)
```

where the left- and right-hand parts are wrapped with lookaround syntax. See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fsm%29%28%3F%3C%3D%5E%5Cs*%3D%3D%3D%2B%5Cr%3F%5Cn%5Cs*%29.*%3F%28%3F%3D%5Cr%3F%5Cn%5Cs*%3D%3D%3D%3D%29&i=Function%20Show-Example%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%23Some%20text%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Another%20text%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Even%20more%20text%20with%20%3A%20like%20that.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Org%3A%20Home%20Garage%20Inc.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Author%3A%20Mr.Smit%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Created%3A%2012%2F12%2F2021%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Last%20update%3A%2012%2F12%2F2021%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Version%3A%201.1.1%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Other%20text%0D%0A%20%20%20%20And%20More%20text%20%7B%20Some%20blocks%20of%20code%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Even%20more%20not%20interesting%20text%20%3A-%29%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D).